# File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Please, how do i fix this error

here's the image link:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj8gJ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `google-services.json` file to app folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to get google-services.json file from the panel when you create the key for your app google allows you to download this file . Then you have to paste this file in your app folder.